# join 3 tables including null values Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

We have three tables in MySQL.
Our query must join:

```
1) student 
2) subject
3) mark
```

**student**

```
id name class year  gender address
1 Ganesh Wagh SSC 2010 male Bhandup, Maharashtra
2 Shailesh Penkar HSC 2010 male Ghatkoper, Mumbai
3 Pooja Palshetkar BE 2014 female Vichumbe, Panvel
```

**subject**

```
id name
1 English
2 Hindi
3 Maths
```

**Mark**

```
id studentid subjectid mark
1 1 1 70
2 1 2 80
3 1 3 90
4 2 1 60
5 2 2 50
6 2 3 60
```

And my desired Output

```
Name        subject mark
Ganesh Wagh English 70
Ganesh Wagh Hindi 80
Ganesh Wagh Maths 90
Shailesh Penkar English 60
Shailesh Penkar Hindi 50
Shailesh Penkar Maths 60
Pooja Palshetkar English 0
Pooja Palshetkar Hindi 0
Pooja Palshetkar Maths 0
```

I try this but it's not working:

```
SELECT 
  student.name, 
  subject.name, 
  mark.mark 
FROM 
(mark AS mark 
RIGHT JOIN student AS student 
  ON student.id = mark.studentid) 
LEFT JOIN subject AS subject 
  ON mark.subjectid = subject.id 
ORDER BY student.id ASC
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes but not helping me

Comment: Show what you have tried, even if it isn't working.

Comment: Code in the question, not in comments, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do a cross join so you get all subjects and all students regardless of whether or not there is a value in mark. Something like

```
select ...
from (student st cross join subject su)
      left join mark m on st.id = mark.studentid and su.id = mark.subjectid
order by student id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it your way as well, if that is your requirement, you just need to take out the 'AS'. If you need an alias, you just write it after the table name. In this case the names are the same, so just leave it out.

```
SELECT 
  student.name, 
  subject.name, 
  mark.mark 
FROM ( mark
RIGHT JOIN student
  ON student.id = mark.studentid )
LEFT JOIN subject
  ON subject.id = mark.subjectid
ORDER BY student.student_id ASC;
```

Comment: The problem with this way is it relies on a record in the Mark table. If a student didn't take a course, there wouldn't be a record here.

Comment: @legxis: I already tried this and this output post in my question, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Which is why I wrote "if it's your requirement". Of course a full join usually makes more sense. I was just pointing out that the SELECT failed because of using 'AS' to give the table aliases.